# What the various design approaches to versioning content in ecommerce

Tags: database, database-design, architecture, e-commerce, relational-database

I am working on an ecommerce application. The products have a lot properties and at this point I have modelled each of them as columns. The  eg. db design is as follows:

```
product (table name) has following columns. (
> name
> category
> etc...etc
properties (table name)
> accepted_payment_mode
> commission_amount
> shipping_charges
> etc...etc.
```

I have over 100 such properties and instead of having them in one table, I split them into more than 5 tables. Any change of the properties value for each product have to go through a business approval flow, before the changes are reflected on the website.

The following are the ways which I know off, but I am not happy with these approaches.

1. Marking the current row as published and creating a new row for edits until it is published. When the  new row is published we mark the earlier row with a version number. This approach looks good for one or two tables, but when the content is split across tables it becomes a huge mess.
2. Having properties in EAV approach and versioning each of the attribute-value pairs. This looks too complicated.
3. Maintaining two databases (frontend and backend). The frontend is used by the website and  had only the published information. The backend is just a replica of the frontend except that all the intermediary updates take place here. This approach needs another audit database to capture all the changes.

   1. Any other approaches I am not aware of.

I could not find a proper piece discussing various approaches to versioning content in e-commerce. What are the good design approaches to solve this problem.

Comment: You may be interested in Jeff's articles, [Is Your Database Under Version Control?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/12/is-your-database-under-version-control.html) and [Get Your Database Under Version Control](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/02/get-your-database-under-version-control.html).

Comment: @eggyal, I have read it long back and we try to follow some similar practice at our end. But what I am asking here is how one goes about designing the system for making sure the changes to rows are handled as per workflow